# Word to describe happy, proud, and sad all at the same time- but the sadness almost outweighs the happiness

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word to describe feeling happy, proud, and sad all at the same time when the sadness almost outweighs the happiness?

I'm feeling this right now - my son has played baseball with the same group of boys since he was 4; he is 12 now. Most of the team is moving to school ball but he has one more year. They just won 2nd place in the gold bracket championship.

Comment: English doesn't have a single word for any kind of emotion you can imagine, you know.

Comment: Perhaps "nostalgia", defined as *a feeling of pleasure and also slight sadness when you think about things that happened in the past* by [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/nostalgia)